# Connecting Docker container to audio output (issue with MPV subprocess in python webapp)

Tags: python, docker, audio, audio-streaming, mpv

I can't play audio with my MPV subprocess in a Docker Container.

Essentially, I have a python webapp (built with Streamlit) that works locally, but not in the cloud-environments I've deployed it to: Azure, Heroku, and Streamlit Cloud.

The problem seems to be with a subprocess (MPV), which can't access the machine's audio devices within the Docker container.

Specifically, the error occurs in [line 30](https://github.com/SuibhneOFoighil/STREAM-test/blob/master/app.py) of my code. I've included the stderr output at the end of the message.

I can list the container's audio devices with mpv --audio-device=help:

```
List of detected audio devices: 
'auto' (Autoselect device) '
alsa' (Default (alsa)) 
'jack' (Default (jack)) '
sdl' (Default (sdl)) 
'sndio' (Default (sndio)
```

I figure I need to link the container to the machine's audio output (like my mac's speakers)... but I'm feeling pretty stumped here! **Any advice is welcome**.

Here's the stderr output of MPV process:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default\nCannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory\nCannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started\nJackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock\nJackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock\nALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name\nALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
```

I've tried a bunch of things, but my inexperience with Docker limits my ability to problem solve.

Comment: In the cloud environments you describe I wouldn't expect to be able to play audio at all – if it worked, noise would come out in Microsoft's data center for Azure, which probably isn't what you're after.  If ALSA actually the right library for your needs, or do you need something more Web-specific?  You seem to have included only the error message but not any of the code in your question; can you [edit] it to include a [mcve]?